# Magento 2.4.3 Layout override is not working

Tags: layout, magento2.4.3

I have recently upgraded Magento 2.3.3 to 2.4.3 and installed claue 2 theme, and created my own child theme in separate folder (not user MGS folder), child theme works fine except that any layout override whether its core magento module or any 3rd party module is not working, for examples, I wanted to override wishilist display page, so I copied:

/vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/layout/wishilist_index_index.xml

file to :
/app/design/frontend/vendor/childtheme/Magento_Wishlist/layout

and made my changes there, and ran commands as:
cache:clean
cache:flush
removed all static content and deployed again

this is happening with every module even if I try to override 3rd party layout file by creating that 3rd party folder in my child theme, its not reflecting.

Answer (score 0):

If the file name is what you write, then you are probably writing the wrong file name. It should be wishlist_index_index.xml.

The file name must be correct to be able to edit the layout.